# CSS/HTML/JS - GetElementByID and html/js element spacing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I am an amatuer at javascript/html/css programing. I developed a java backend and I am in the process of developing a convenient frontend webui for it. I want to display buttons in a tree format. All has been successful accept two things: 1) I cannot get the spacing on my buttons to work. I am trying to attempt even spacing between buttons on each line. 2) I cannot get an element by a property ID even using onload. Inspecting the page shows the element and the ID. Apologies if my code is sloppy.

Image removed because everyone seems to focus on it for the wrong reason.

```js
getTree();
addButtons();
window.onload = function() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  canvas_arrow(ctx, document.getElementById("rank1").x,
    document.getElementById("rank1").y,
    document.getElementById("rank2").x,
    document.getElementById("rank2").y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
  ctx.stroke();
};

function addButtons() {
  fetch('/api/tree').then(async(response) => {
    await response.json().then(result => {
      let i = 0;
      result.forEach(function(item) {
        let section = document.getElementById("rankButtons");
        let element = document.createElement("button");
        if (i !== item["tier"]) {
          section.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          section.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          i = item["tier"];
        }
        element.id = item["rankID"];
        element.value = item["rankName"];
        element.name = "rankButton";
        element.textContent = item["rankName"];
        section.appendChild(element);
      });
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
function canvas_arrow(context, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {
let headLength = 10; // length of head in pixels
let dx = toX - fromX;
let dy = toY - fromY;
let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
context.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
context.lineTo(toX, toY);
context.lineTo(toX - headLength * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toY - headLength * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
context.moveTo(toX, toY);
context.lineTo(toX - headLength * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toY - headLength * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
}
```

```css
.header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #555;
}

body {
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid white;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #CC0033, #3300CC);
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid #30273a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #8d78a5;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 750px;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding: 0 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#viewport {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

tree.html
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px">Available Ranks</summary>
  <pre v-pre="true" class="prismjs line-numbers" style="text-align: center">
        <table id="ranks" class="table table-striped" style="font-size:12px"></table>
    </pre>
</details>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
<div id="content">
  <div id="rankButtons"></div>
</div>
```

Here it is again because the other guy edited it out...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="background-color: black">
<head>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="./RDQ-512-Logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title id="title">Rank Up Tree</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tree.css">
</head>
<body>

<details>
    <summary style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px">Available Ranks</summary>
    <pre v-pre="true" class="prismjs line-numbers" style="text-align: center">
        <table id="ranks" class="table table-striped" style="font-size:12px"></table>
    </pre>
</details>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
<div id="content">
    <div id="rankButtons"></div>
</div>
<script src="tree.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could u post html as a code, not as an image

Comment: I did. A user edited it to be runnable though you cannot without my backend. The image is the console to show my backend variables/tags loading.

Comment: yes, but it includes only part about canvas, not buttons, and doesnt include line with script tag (not jquery one) which makes it harder to analyze the problem

Comment: The buttons are creating in the javascript code above under addButtons() functoin

Comment: I still would like to ask where does <script src="tree.js"> is relatively to canvas, content etc

Comment: If you want useful help, trim out _everything_ that is not needed to reproduce the problem, and make it runnable here on stack overflow, by linking to any image - doesn't have to be your real image.

Comment: @Allure I show my entire front end code. The other user edited it out to try and make it runnable. Not sure why since you need backend for that.

Comment: @Eureka How would I go about doing that without the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You are over-complicating your functions

```
function addButtons() {
  fetch('/api/tree').then(async(response) => {
    await response.json().then(result => {
      let i = 0;
      result.forEach(function(item) {
        let section = document.getElementById("rankButtons");
        let element = document.createElement("button");
        if (i !== item["tier"]) {
          section.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          section.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          i = item["tier"];
        }
        element.id = item["rankID"];
        element.value = item["rankName"];
        element.name = "rankButton";
        element.textContent = item["rankName"];
        section.appendChild(element);
      });
    })
    return true
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Async functions are designed to be easy to read.

Surely the top only needs to be:

```
async function addButtons(){
    const response = await fetch('/api/tree');
    const result = await response.json();

    let i=0;
    // ... etc

}
```

#### You are not calling `addButtons` anywhere

You say this is your entire front-end code. Well that doesn't call addButtons.

#### I suspect you want to create the buttons first

You seem to be trying in your `onLoad` to access elements with ID=`rank1` etc, which seem to be being created by `addButtons`.

Therefore did you want to run `addButtons` first?

If so, since `addButtons` is asynchronous, you should `await` it. (I have added a `return true` to the function as a reminder that it will return a promise.)

```
window.onload = async function() {
  await addButtons()
  let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  canvas_arrow(ctx, document.getElementById("rank1").x,
    document.getElementById("rank1").y,
    document.getElementById("rank2").x,
    document.getElementById("rank2").y);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
  ctx.stroke();
};
```

Comment: Edited to show the original addButtons call.

Comment: Thank you. I think it was my failure to understand the async syntax.

Comment: When using your method above. I get the following errors: tree.js:87 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.forEach is not a function

Comment: My mistake - should have read     `const result = await response.json();`  - I have updated

Comment: "Edited to show the original addButtons call. " ---- Aha! The problem with that is that the buttons are created asynchronously (they have to wait for the `fetch` to happen) so the rest of the code will not be able to "see" the buttons and their ids etc.

Comment: Yeah I figured that one out. Just need a solution to my css problem now. Thanks!

Comment: Remember to mark as accepted 8-)

Comment: I can only mark one accepted. If nobody answers my other issue I will mark yours accepted.

Comment: OK I had forgotten about the CSS question - I was so engrossed in this `addButton` puzzle. I suspect they may not be able to help, because we cannot reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: That makes sense. I might just have to start the CSS over. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. May just need a break. So frustrating ha. Ill mark yours completed.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Eureka for the help! After redoing the css and javascript using findPos this is the answer:

```js
function findPos(obj){
    let curLeft = obj.offsetWidth / 2;
    let curTop = obj.offsetHeight / 2;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curLeft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curTop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj === obj.offsetParent);
        return {x:curLeft,y:curTop};
    }
}

window.onload = async function () {
    await addButtons();
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    let pos = findPos(document.getElementById("rank1"));
    let pos2 = findPos(document.getElementById("rank2"));
    canvas_arrow(ctx, pos.x, pos.y, pos2.x, pos2.y - 10);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.stroke();
};

function canvas_arrow(context, fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {
    let headLength = 10; // length of head in pixels
    let dx = toX - fromX;
    let dy = toY - fromY;
    let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    context.moveTo(fromX, fromY);
    context.lineTo(toX, toY);
    context.lineTo(toX - headLength * Math.cos(angle - Math.PI / 6), toY - headLength * Math.sin(angle - Math.PI / 6));
    context.moveTo(toX, toY);
    context.lineTo(toX - headLength * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI / 6), toY - headLength * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI / 6));
}

async function addButtons() {
    const response = await fetch('/api/tree');
    const result = await response.json();
    let i = 0;
    result.forEach(function (item) {
        let section = document.getElementById("rankButtons");
        let element = document.createElement("button");
        if (i !== item["tier"]) {
            section.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            section.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            i = item["tier"];
        }
        element.id = item["rankID"];
        element.value = item["rankName"];
        element.name = "rankButton";
        element.style.background = "linear-gradient(to bottom right, #CC0033, #3300CC)";
        element.style.padding = "5px";
        element.textContent = item["rankName"];
        section.appendChild(element);
    });
}
```

```css
.header img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #555;
}

body {
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid white;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td {
    white-space:pre;
    padding: 5px;
}

#container {
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    border-color: white;
}

#rankButtons {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="background-color: black">
<head>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="./RDQ-512-Logo.jpg" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title id="title">Rank Up Tree</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tree.css">
</head>
<body>
<details>
    <summary style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px">Available Ranks</summary>
    <pre v-pre="true" class="prismjs line-numbers" style="text-align: center">
        <table id="ranks" class="table table-striped" style="font-size:12px"></table>
    </pre>
</details>
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>
    <div id="rankButtons"></div>
</div>
<script src="tree.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```